# Determine the general solutions of $x'''-5x''+8x'-4x=0 , t∈R$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have found the following exercise in one of my courses:

determine the general solutions of $x'''-5x''+8x'-4x=0 , t∈R$

How do you solve this?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx

Comment: Was this exercise in a textbook? If so, I'm sure there are examples very similar to this if you read the section.

Answer (score 2):

This equation may be solved by solving its characteristic equation. First, take it that $x(t) = e^{at}$. Note that:
$$x' = ae^{at},$$
$$x'' = a^2e^{at},$$ and
$$x''' = a^3e^{at}.$$

Therefore the equation can be written :

$$
a^3e^{at} - 5a^2e^{at}+8ae^{at}-4e^{at}\;=\;0.
$$

Divide each side of the equation by $e^{at}$ (this is clearly never $0$), to reduce the equation to:

$$
a^3 - 5a^2+8a-4\;=\;0.
$$

Dividing the cubic polynomial on the left-hand side of the equation (which is called the *characteristic polynomial* of the equation) by $(a-1)$ shows us that this polynomial may be factored as $(a-1)(a^2-4a+4)=(a-1)(a-2)^2$. This equation has roots $a=1$ and $a=2$, so we know that $e^{t}$ and $e^{2t}$. Given that $2$ is a double root, our general solution is:

$$
x(t)=c_0e^{t}+c_1e^{2t}+c_2te^{2t}
$$where $c_0$, $c_1$, and $c_2$ are constants. If you are unfamiliar with this sort of approach, you can look up why we include terms like $c_2te^{2t}$ when the characteristic polynomial has a repeated root.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a 3rd order, linear, homogeneous Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) with constant coefficients.  In general, *n*-th order ODE's with constant coefficients can be solved using the [*characteristic equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)) of the ODE, which in this case will be:
$$\gamma^3-5\gamma^2+8\gamma-4=0$$This equation is found by assuming the result will be of the form $x=Ce^{\gamma t}$ for some $\gamma$, which is a fair assumption in the case of *constant coefficient* equations only.

Once you find the values of $\gamma$ where this is true, your solution will be of the form $x=C_1e^{\gamma_1 t}+C_2e^{\gamma_2 t}+C_3e^{\gamma_3 t}$ (as an *n*-th order linear ODE has at most *n* linearly independent solutions), where $C_1,\,C_2,\,C_3$ depend on your initial conditions.  So, your problem has been reduced to finding the roots of a 3rd degree polynomial.

From the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), we can check certain values of $\gamma$ without resorting to using a computer.  By inspection, $\gamma_1=2$ is a solution.  So, the polynomial will factor as $(\gamma-2)(a\gamma^2+b\gamma+c)=0$ for some $a,b,c$.  Using polynomial long division (which I've never really been able to show efficiently in LaTeX), this reduces to $(\gamma-2)(\gamma^2-3\gamma+2)$.  To find the other two roots, we can just use the quadratic formula, giving $\gamma=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-8}}{2}=\frac{3\pm 1}{2}$.  So, our 3 roots are $\gamma_1=2$, $\gamma_2=2$, and $\gamma_3=1$. Unfortunately, two of our roots are equal, so we can't just say $x=C_1e^{2 t}+C_2e^{2 t}+C_3e^{t}$ and be on our merry way.  Instead, when we have a root of the characteristic equation with some multiplicity, we let our solution be $(C_0+C_1t+\dots+C_nt^n)e^{\gamma t}$, where $n$ is the multiplicity of that root.  For us, we have multiplicity 2, so our solution is:

$$x=(C_0+C_1t)e^{2 t}+C_2e^{t}$$

Note that sometimes (most of the time in my experience) you see this written as $x=C_0e^{2 t}+C_1te^{2 t}+C_2e^{t}$, but I feel that writing it my way allows the "rule" of dealing with multiplicities to be explained a little more concisely.

Comment: You've factored the cubic incorrectly. Observe that $ \gamma =1$ is a solution too.

Comment: Whoops.  It appears between my scratch paper and posting the solution I changed a "-3" to a "-4".